# ASP execute stored procedure with Null

Tags: asp-classic, ado

In asp.net can use dbnull.value to send Null value to db.
How to use in ASP?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP, you need to use the keyword **NULL** as the null value for the stored procedure.

Note: don't use vbNull as this evaluates to 1 rather than null.